# I want to display result set, Counts for all Level whether it is Zero "0" or Not in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run this query:

```
SELECT 
    M.Desc AS LevelDescription, 
    COUNT(M.Id) AS Counts
FROM 
    Master_Levels M 
LEFT JOIN 
    Counsent C ON (M.Id = C.LevelId)
GROUP BY 
    M.Desc, M.Id, C.LevelId, C.ProcedureId, C.IsAccepts
HAVING 
    (C.IsAccepts = 'Yes') 
    AND (C.ProcedureId = 3) 
    AND (M.Id IN (1, 2, 3, 4))
```

It shows only non-zero counts, I want result like this:

[image: result]

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Side note, the `HAVING` is generally for clauses which involve at least one aggregate function. Those that aren't should be in the `WHERE`. This also enables to use clauses on columns that *aren't* defined in the `GROUP BY` and aren't being aggregated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the restrictions in the `HAVING` clause belong in the respective `ON` clause of the joins:

```sql
SELECT M.Desc AS LevelDescription, COUNT(C.LevelId) AS Counts
FROM Master_Levels M
LEFT JOIN Counsent C
    ON M.Id = C.LevelId AND C.ProcedureId = 3 AND C.IsAccepts = 'Yes'
WHERE M.Id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
GROUP BY M.Desc;
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen for prompt response. its working perfectly.

Comment: See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) @MugalMehboob .